# Would my SEO be impacted if I migrated posts from Tumblr to a hosted WordPress solution?

Tags: seo, wordpress, migration, tumblr

I'm curious about both the positive and negative benefits of migrating old posts that were written on a Tumblr blog with a custom domain to a self-hosted WordPress solution.

I've seen many people mention better SEO from a self-hosted WordPress solution, as well as the convenience of having all blog content in one place.

If I were to migrate everything to the self-hosted WordPress, I would create `301` redirects from the old post URLs to the new post URLs in order to preserve SEO. However, are there downsides to this? Am I going to experience an SEO hit?

URL example from my old Tumblr blog:

`http://blog.example.com`

URL example from my new self-hosted WordPress solution:

`http://www.websiteurl.com/blog`

Comment: Does the last edit work for moving away from an opinion based question?

Comment: Not completely, but I edited it a bit more for you and reopened.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have any negative SEO impacts if you do the transition the way you are describing, with 301 redirects.  Per a Google Webmaster Tools Help page, https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en, 301 redirects are useful if you are moving your site to a new domain and want to make the transition as seamless as possible, which is exactly what you are doing.

Just make sure that:

1. You register and verify your new domain right away and fill out the Change of Address form in WMT (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en)
2. Your redirects are 1:1, meaning that the old page goes directly to it's new page, and not the home page of your new domain.
3. Resubmit your sitemap from your old site once the 301's are in place, then submit the sitemap for the new site.

Answer (score -2):

Its not have nay negative SEO, USE the  301 redirects from old to new pages show your website not gets any impacts.

Comment: This answer doesn't say anything that the other answer doesn't already say.