# Google Webmaster Tools doesn't show any indexed pages after redirection

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, google-index

I have a website that was properly configured in Google Webmaster Tools and indexed in Google.

Then I created a redirection from this website to my new website so that any request to:

`www.mysite.fr`

goes to:

`www.mysite.com`

I have added the new site to Google Webmaster Tools, but so far the number of indexed pages is zero.

If I check the stats of my old website, it seems they were updated with the data of the new website (sitemap and indexed pages).

This is very confusing, can someone explain what's going on?  Is this expected behavior after a `301` redirect?

Comment: How long has the 301 redirect been in place?

Comment: 8 days since the 301.

Comment: God may have created the world in 7 days, but don't expect anything from Google in 8. It can take 30-60 days for it all to settle in. It will just take time. It is hard to be patient- I know! Especially when it is your website. But in this case, patience is what is prescribed.

Comment: well at least you made me laugh :) Thanks for the advice, I'll wait then !

Comment: so was your patient paid?

Comment: yep, all good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here:  [Would my SEO be impacted if I migrated posts from Tumblr to a hosted WordPress solution?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67104/would-my-seo-be-impacted-if-i-migrated-posts-from-tumblr-to-a-hosted-wordpress-s/67122#67122)

In short I would make sure you fill out the Change of Address form in WMT (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en) and you resubmit your sitemap from your old site (so Google picks up the 301's), then submit the sitemap for the new site.

Also, try going to Google and do a "search" of your site prefixed with "site:".  example:  `site:www.google.com`  You'll see if your new site is actually visible or not, regardless of what WMT says.